# Dynamic module loading using __import__

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I want to make a function that loads all the .py files in a directory, and imports them using

__import__(), but I keep getting an **ImportError: No module named toolboxtool1**.

This is file structure:

```
project/dirreader.py
project/tools/toolboxtool1.py
project/tools/toolboxtool2.py
project/tools/toolboxtool3.py
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
import os
os.chdir(os.getcwd()+"/tools/")
stuff = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
for i in range(0,len(stuff)):
    if stuff[i][-3:] == ".py":
        stuff[i] = stuff[i][:-3]
    else:
        pass
modules = map(__import__, stuff)
```

Comment: What is the text of your import error?  It seems like it could be a relative path problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try prefixing the module names with `"tools."`

```
stuff[i] = 'tools.' + stuff[i][:-3]
```

because the modules you are trying to import are inside `tools` module package.